# Real time CPU% by process monitoring script in AIX 6.1

Tags: bash, shell, sh, cpu-usage, aix

I'm trying to write a script that monitors real time CPU% load in AIX 6.1-servers by process(PID), and have been searching for this both in IBMs documentation and all over stackoverflow.

I only find examples of people using, for example

```
ps aux
```

Needless to say, thats not what I need, since it only monitors how much CPU% the process has been using over the session time, which in my case is quite long.
 The information I need is contained in topas and nmon, but I don't know how to grab a snapshot of this information for each individual moment.

```
top
```

Does not exist in AIX systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by making a script that generates 30second tprof logs and iterates through them adding up the process threads by PID and reaching a sum that equals more or less a real-time CPU load% process list.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a function I use to search and grab CPU load from nmon data log 

function fetch_UARG_process_by_pid () 
{

#Check_Argument $1 $2

#parameter initialization 
filesource=$1
cpuvalue=$2
readarray -t X <<< "$(grep TOP $filesource)"
length=${#X[@]}

#echo " this is the length of my array : $length"
#you have to start from 2 to avoid the first lines that describe the content of the file
#TOP,%CPU Utilisation
#TOP,+PID,Time,%CPU,%Usr, Sys,Size,ResSet,ResText,ResData,ShdLib,MinorFault,MajorFault,Command

  for ((i = 2; i != length; i++)); do
    echo ${X[i]} | awk -F "," '{print $2 , $4}' | while read processid n 
        do
                     if (( $(echo "$n > $cpuvalue " |bc -l) )); 
                     then 
             echo    "the value of CPU usage is: $n"
             echo    "the Linux PID is : $processid "
             echo    "And the short desciption of the process:" 
             echo ${X[i]} | awk -F "," '{print $14}'
             echo -e "And the long desciption of the process:" 
                         grep UARG $1 | grep $processid | awk -F "," '{print $5}'
             echo -e "\n"
             fi
        done
  done

}
```